# Webassembly multiple modules?

Tags: webassembly

Lets assume we have the following:

```
(module)
```

Just a simple module with no functions, locals, memory and all the fancy stuff. 
Now what if I dont want to overpopulate my module? I mean id like to have two modules but I obviously get an error when trying to compile something like:

```
(module)
(module)
```

So is there a way to give each module its own memory or id? Or is there any way to do so? Does it even make sense? Im just saying since a module can really become huge.

What im trying to accomplish is to communicate between two modules since I believe it makes sense to prevent a module to become too big. Im new to webassembly so maybe what im saying sounds crazy.

For compilation tests I use https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebAssembly modules are similar to executables on your disk: they haven't been loaded into memory.

A WebAssembly instance is what makes a module come to life. You can instantiate the same module multiple times, or instantiate multiple modules. Instantiation will load the module, compile / validate it, initialize its globals and memory (if any), populate exports, and then call its start function.

Your examples use the s-expression syntax, but you don't specify how you're executing WebAssembly. The s-expression themselves are just text, an embedder is needed to run the compiled result!

In a JavaScript embedding [the API](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/JS.md) has the `WebAssembly.Module` and `WebAssembly.Instance` constructors, as well as the `WebAssembly.compile` and `WebAssembly.instantiate` functions (either works, `WebAssembly.instantiate` is simpler / better). You pass the instance constructor / function an import object. WebAssembly memories are either created by declaring a memory section in the binary (then a memory is automatically created at instantiation time), or by exporting it through the import object.

You can even perform dynamic linking by creating multiple modules, instantiating them with sharing of a memory between them, and having them import / export each other's functions.

In the spec interpreter you can declare multiple modules which get validated, and you have extra helpers to poke at them. See [this test](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/blob/master/test/core/binary.wast) which starts with:

```
(module "\00asm\01\00\00\00")
(module "\00asm" "\01\00\00\00")
(module $M1 "\00asm\01\00\00\00")
(module $M2 "\00asm" "\01\00\00\00")

(assert_malformed (module "") "unexpected end")
(assert_malformed (module "\01") "unexpected end")
```

Comment: Im still using the explorer provided by mozilla (still experimenting on there) https://mbebenita.github.io/WasmExplorer/. Later im going to install the real thing but I assume the explorer uses the same compiler as the ones we can download from git etc

Comment: Do I understand that javascript is absolutely needed for this task of making modules work with each other?

Comment: WebAssembly doesn't dictate which compiler you can use. LLVM+Emscripten is  good choice, there's a GCC experiment and I'm sure we'll see more in the future.

Comment: So basically we need some bridge which is javascript. So I have module A and export data, import to javascript and javascript can use that data to pass it to Module B and so A and B communicate via the apis provided by javascript?

Comment: JavaScript isn't *needed* but it's the best available embedding right now. You could also try the spec interpreter, binaryen's interpreter, etc... WebAssembly was designed for [non-web embeddings](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/NonWeb.md) to work as well. Right now JavaScript is simply the best embedding.

Comment: WebAssembly has imports and exports. In a JavaScript embedding: 1. JS can call wasm exports; 2. wasm can call JS through imports; 3. wasm can call wasm through each of their import/export. Note 3. is different from going through JS because you can pass i64 around (which JS doesn't support), and in theory it's more efficient.

Comment: You mentioned dynamic linking though where multiple modules can share memory. This is exactly what Im trying to do. This basically means module A can communicate with module B and share memory around.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a specification for linkable WebAssembly modules](https://github.com/WebAssembly/tool-conventions/blob/master/Linking.md). It is non-official and optional, but if you create your WebAssembly modules so that they conform to this specification, you can use a linker like [LLVM’s `lld`](https://lld.llvm.org/WebAssembly.html) to link them.